# mysql WHERE clause not working

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I would like to select multiple values in where clause but it is not selecting anything.

This is the select query I have:

```
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE  id IN (4, 5)  ORDER BY id desc'
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any records with an ID of 4 or 5?

Comment: Show us.  Also, does the query return any errors? What's the line that executes the query look like?  Give us more to work with, because your query looks legit, but there's other pieces that we are missing.

Comment: do you actually have a table named 'table'?  Are you actually connected to a database?  Do you actually have those single quotes as part of the string?

Comment: What is the data type of the ID field?   If it's `char`, the value might be padded.   If there are records with an id of 4 or 5, there must be a type conversion mismatch, or else you'd get records.

Comment: ID fields traditionally are INTEGER, not VARCHAR.  As @Curt is pointing out, you probably have padding or something going on.

Comment: oh yeah I changed it to `INT` and now it works but what if I want to use varchar. this is just a test I have columns with varchar and I would like to do the samething for those too?

Comment: You'll have to know what the *actual* value of that column is, then.

Comment: And / or you could use the [mysql TRIM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function to ensure it doesn't have any spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, the reason that the query is failing is because the column is a `varchar` and you are using `int` values in your `IN` clause.  MySQL does not convert the type if you quote the numbers then your query will work with `varchar`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine your table has no data with id = 4 or id = 5.

Try

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE  id = 4
```

Does that return anything either?  I would bet no.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just 
`'SELECT * FROM table WHERE  (id = '4' OR id= '5')  ORDER BY id desc'`

Comment: Because the OP wants to use IN, which is very useful.

Comment: More than one way to skin a cat. Not sure if that warranted a downvote.

Comment: Ironically, I am not one of the ones who downvoted.  I don't think it was worth a downvote, either - I was just pointing out the benefits of IN.  Syntactically, it's much simpler to write an IN query than one that lists many OR clauses.

Comment: Very true, although if there are only 2 variables in your query and you can't get the query to work using IN, you might need to take a step back and make sure the more direct way works.